# Get pluginId stored in the IPreferenceNode in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin, in my plugin I want to get another plugin ID. I use the following code:

```java
    PreferenceManager pm = PlatformUI.getWorkbench( ).getPreferenceManager();
    List<IPreferenceNode> list = pm.getElements(PreferenceManager.PRE_ORDER);
    String pluginid;        

   // restoreDefValues("org.eclipse.ant.ui");

    for(IPreferenceNode node : list){
     the code to find the node related to the plugin;
   }
```

When I debug the program, I can clearly see that in variable node(IPreferenceNode), it has the value of the pluginId. However, I check the document of IPreferenceNode, it seems that the neither IPreferenceNode nor the class PreferenceNode, provide a method to return the value of pluginId. I tried `node.toString()` as well, couldn't get the pluginId. So what should I do? Is there any other ways to get a plugin ID from another plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preference nodes created using the `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` extension point will actually be instances of `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode`. The super class of this (`WorkbenchPreferenceExtensionNode`) contains the plugin id.

These classes are **internal** so you should not try to use them directly. However they implement `org.eclipse.ui.IPluginContribution` which can be used and has a `getPluginId()` method.

So something like:

```java
if (node instanceof IPluginContribution) {
  pluginId = ((IPluginContribution)node).getPluginId();
}
```

should work.

Comment: Hi, greg, thanks very much for your comment. I was fool, the problem was simple, I just need to upcasting the interface. I did it like this: WorkbenchPreferenceExtensionNode wnode =(WorkbenchPreferenceExtensionNode) node . In WorkbenchPreferenceExtensionNode, it provides a method to get the pluginId directly :)

Comment: Do not use internal classes, they can be changed without notice.